# Primesense Data Format

Tags: ros, data, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have successfully built the OpenNI package on the QorIQ processor platform. The QorIQ prcessor of Freescale ia based on the e500v2 core.

I used the USB part of the OpenNI to configure and read the Data from the primesense RD1.09 module.

However, what I get from the Primesense Module into the platform is a byte stream that represents raw data. This is achieved by continiously read the corresponding Bulk Endpoints

Do you have any documentation/Information on the format of this byte stream? Do you have any documentation on how to transform the byte streams to the depth map and rgb map?

I don't have any information about the header, start and end of real data.

As I don't know how the byte stream is composed, its is difficult to transform it to the depth- and rgb map.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56725/primesense-data-format/) by [alfonsokame](https://answers.ros.org/users/4326/alfonsokame/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some technical information about the protocol, control packets of the kinect etc can be found at the openkinect project: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Protocol_Documentation

I don't know if this information is valid for the newer PrimeSense-sensors, but maybe this points you to the right direction?

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1